# Removing my own comments is not "voting"

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, comments, user-interface, deleted-comments

I cannot remove more than one comment of my own every 5 seconds.  I find this annoying.

Sometimes I only opt to write a reply when I realize I have found multiple issues to comment on, then wrap them up in an answer instead, and remove the comments. This should hardly be more complex than it has to be -- I realize that there is a reason for the time window for voting on comments, but removing my own comments should be exempted from this time window.

Comment: I'm considering working on [this feature-request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382/can-we-get-x-comment-votes-per-x-minutes-rather-than-one-vote-per-5-seconds) that should alleviate your issue, too.

Comment: As an aside: the self-deletion rate-limiting was added mostly to stem "rage quitting".  I'll have to look at the flagging system, but we might have auto-flags in place to detect such behavior now (and if not, we can add them).  These auto-flags could alert mods when someone is destroying their good content at too fast a rate.

Comment: @JarrodDixon as has been said repeatedly on meta, comments are not intended to be forever, but rather transitory.  If someone rage-deletes all of their comments, we should not care.

Comment: @Yakk that's true, but in practice, lots of good information is still languishing in comment threads.

Comment: @JarrodDixon The message is also incorrect. Instead of showing "`You can only submit a comment vote every 5 seconds`", it should say "`You may only delete a comment every 5 seconds`".

Comment: @Yakk: brb, deleting this entire thread.

Comment: @Jarrod Dixon: We used to have a very short trial run of auto-flags for mass-deleted comments. The verdict was that they weren't nearly as useful as auto-flags for mass-deleted posts. Generally if a user is ragequitting, they're going to want to mass-delete their posts as well anyway, something we already handle as usual.

Comment: @boltclock I have seen more interesting comments expunged with that justification on the main site, like the one pointing out the question that launched silk road.  ;)

Comment: @Yakk: you said it, "justification". There's a difference between a reason and a justification. If a mod wants to remove comments, then there's some reason why they made the judgement that those comments are clutter in need of tidying, but all the *justification* they need is "comments are temporary". Rage-quitters, on the other hand, can't rightly appeal to that justification if there's some reason a mod wants the content to remain :-)